# PDO MSSQL - wrong BIGINT value returned

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, bigint

I'm trying to query against a BIGINT primary key on a MSSQL database and some of the returned values turn up rounded, different than the ones stored in the database:

[See screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhpPr.png)

9200000000000359 exists in the DB, as well as 9200000000000361. Querying against any of these two values will return 9200000000000360 (side note: this value does not exists in the database).

It seems that the values are first (wrongly) converted to binary and when converted back they result in different values than the original ones. But I'm using PHP 5.6 on a 64bit machine, not 32bit. Also this happens when using both dblib and odbc drivers.

Is there any setting I can make on the SQLServer or in the php.ini config to get the correct values?

Comment: Strangely, what's the `string(16)`?

Comment: what happens if you put single quotes `'` around your 16 digit integers?

Comment: @Abela I don't think it may change a thing, as both are taken as strings. EDIT: That by the way, is an output string, you can't change the quotes.

Comment: That is a var_dump of the result. The bigint "920...." represented as string has 16 characters long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Yii makes a conversion to float on the result. Even plain PHP 7 on a 64 bit machine returns the following output:

```
php > echo (int)(float)9200000000000359;
9200000000000360
```

Using plain PHP and PDO, the correct output is returned:

```
$db = new PDO($dbc->connectionString, $dbc->username, $dbc->password);
$stmt = $db->query("...... WHERE id = 9200000000000359");
var_dump($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)[0]['id']);

// output:
array(1) {
    [0] => string(16) "9200000000000359"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP under Windows, then you should upgrade to PHP 7+.

> 64-bit platforms usually have a maximum value of about 9E18, except on
>   Windows prior to PHP 7, where it was always 32 bit.

From [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)

> x86_64 Builds
>   The x64 builds of PHP 5 for Windows are experimental, and do not provide 64-bit integer or large file support.
>
> PHP 7 provides full 64-bit support. The x64 builds of PHP 7 support native 64-bit integers, LFS, memory_limit and much more.

From [windows.php.net](http://windows.php.net/index.php)

Comment: This issue happens on both PHP 7.0.11 on my local macOS Sierra and PHP 5.6.25 on the CentOS 64bit server (CentOS release 6.7 / Linux 2.6.32-573.el6.x86_64).